# Optimise the code to find max consecutive points in a straight line(row,column or diagonal) in a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, time-complexity

I need to find the maximum number of consecutive points in a straight line(row,column or diagonal) in a matrix .

For eg:- if it is a 4*4 matrix
input is (1#1,2#2,3#3,2#1) the answer should be 3 as the max consecutive points in diagonal is 3.

My code is successfully getting executed with expected results.But the code complexity is very high.

Can someone please suggest the best approach complexity wise.

Below is my code:

```
// Get the max number of Continuous points in a matrix row
private static int getMaxContinuousPointsInRow(boolean[][] matrix, int row){
    int maxCount = 0;
    int currCount = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    while(pos < matrix[row].length){
        currCount = 0;
    while(pos < matrix[row].length && !matrix[row][pos])
        pos++;
    if(pos >= matrix[row].length)
        break;
    while(pos < matrix[row].length && matrix[row][pos]){
        currCount++;
        pos++;
    }
    if(currCount > maxCount)
        maxCount = currCount;
    }
    return maxCount;
}

// Get the max number of Continuous points in a matrix row
private static int getMaxContinuousPointsInCol(boolean[][] matrix, int col) {
    int maxCount = 0;
    int currCount = 0;
    int pos = 0;

    while (pos < matrix.length) {
        currCount = 0;
    while (pos < matrix.length && !matrix[pos][col])
        pos++;
    if(pos >= matrix.length)
        break;
    while (pos < matrix.length && matrix[pos][col]) {
        currCount++;
        pos++;
    }
    if (currCount > maxCount)
        maxCount = currCount;
    }
    return maxCount;
}

// Get the max number of Continuous points in a matrix diagonal right starting from position (row,col)
private static int getMaxContinuousPointsInDiagonalRight(boolean[][] matrix, int row, int col) {
    int maxCount = 0;
    int currCount = 0;
    int i = row, j = col;
    while (i < matrix.length && j < matrix[row].length) {
        currCount = 0;
    while (i < matrix.length && j < matrix[row].length && !matrix[i][j]){
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    if(i >= matrix.length || j >= matrix[row].length)
        break;
    while (i < matrix.length && j < matrix[row].length && matrix[i][j]) {
        currCount++;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    if (currCount > maxCount)
        maxCount = currCount;
    }
    return maxCount;
}

public static int function_called_by_main_method(int input1, int input2, String[] input3) {
    // create a boolean matrix of size  input1 x input2
    // M[i][j] = true if  input3 contains a point i#j, else M[i][j] = false
    boolean M[][] = new boolean[input1 + 1][input2 + 1];
    // initialize the matrix with all false values
    for(int i=0; i <= input1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j <= input2; j++){
            M[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    // process each value in input3 and populate the matrix
    for (String s : input3) {
        // extract row, column value
        String[] data = s.split("#");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        int j = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        M[i][j] = true;
    }
    // get max number of Continuous points among all matrix rows
    int max = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row <= input1; row++){
        int rowMax = getMaxContinuousPointsInRow(M, row);
        if(rowMax > max)
        max = rowMax;
    }
    // get max number of Continuous points among all matrix rows and columns
    for (int col = 0; col <= input2; col++) {
        int colMax = getMaxContinuousPointsInCol(M, col);
        if (colMax > max)
        max = colMax;
    }
    // get max number of Continuous points among all matrix rows, columns and right diagonals
    for(int col = input2 ; col >= 0; col--){
        int diagMax = getMaxContinuousPointsInDiagonalRight(M, 0, col);
        if(diagMax > max)
        max = diagMax;
    }
    for(int row = 1 ; row <= input1; row++){
        int diagMax = getMaxContinuousPointsInDiagonalRight(M, row, 0);
        if(diagMax > max)
            max = diagMax;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: *For eg:- if it is a 4*4 matrix input is (1#1,2#2,3#3,2#1) the answer should be 3 as the max consecutive points in diagonal is 3.* I havent understood this example cause I dont know how to interpret it

Comment: @user7185318 i and j are rows and columns of a matrix 
if a point falls in 1st row 2nd column , the input is 1#2

Comment: What do you mean with consecutive ? Please provide the 4x4 matrix  that goes with *(1#1,2#2,3#3,2#1)*

Comment: for eg :- 1#1 , 1#2 are consecutive in row
              1#1, 1#3 are not

              1#1,2#2 are consecutive in diagonal
              1#1, 3#3 are not

              1#1,2#1 are consecutive in column
               1#1,3#1 are not

Comment: What means consecutive : Example are the points (0,0) (1,1) (2,2) consecutive ? Is it the value you are looking for sqrt(x*x+y*y) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try parallelism with the java 8 streams, on a dumb brute force approach.

```
class Coord {
    int i;
    int j;
}

List<Coord[]> allLineCoords = calculateLinesForMatrix(rows, columns);

Comparator<Coord[]> comparator = (coords1, coords2) ->
        length(matrix, coords1) - length(matrix, coords2);

Coord[] maxCoords = allLineCoords.parallelStream()
    .max(comparator);

// or for just the max length:

int maxLength = (int) allLineCoords.parallelStream()
    .mapToInt(coords -> length(matrix, coords))
    .max();
```

Very unsatisfying is the missing intelligence. And the parallelism only scales to the number of cores of your computer.